# Change TFS field when children or parent exist in a certain state

Tags: tfs

We have a custom field on User Story that I would like to have automatically change based on child Task state(s). For example, if all children are Closed, it would change to Closed, and if one child changes to something else, it would change to something else. The logic could live in either place as far as I'm concerned. I found how to change a field based on another field, but not how to check and aggregate the fields of children (or parent). Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box way to support this. You could use [TFS Aggregator](https://github.com/tfsaggregator/tfsaggregator/wiki) for this purpose.

If this does not do it, you could create a Work Item Event Handler that reacts to changes in the state of the Task work items. 
See this [blog post](http://vgaltes.com/index.php/2013/04/14/create-a-team-foundation-server-event-handler/) for details on how to implement a Work Item Event Handler.

Comment: Excellent, these look like just what I want. Thanks for the quick response.